# Useref, usestate, useeffect issues

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to create a function that selects an HTML element and changes the value in it to the value in another element using the ref, state, and effect hooks but I can't get the right effect I want

```
const Service = () => {
const [selected, setSelected] = 
 useState(false);
let change = useRef(null);
const[title, setTitle] = useState("");
useEffect(() => {
setTitle(change.current.children(0))
})
const Changer = (e)=>{
e.preventDefault()
const style = e.target;
if(selected === false){
  
  console.log(`you clicked ${style}`);
}
setSelected( current => !current);
// let style={background: selected ? 
'#6EEFB1' : ''};
// if (selected === true){
//   setSelected(false)
//   // let style= {styleObject.li}
  
// }else{
//   setSelected(true)
// }
}
return(
 <section className={selected ? 
 "serviceClicked" : "services"}>
  <h1>Our Services</h1>
  <div className='service-content'>
    <div className='service-text' ref=. 
    {change}>
    <h2></h2>
    <p>
      Syse infrans att dedade. Redar 
      fäsat. Älogi hypol. Antere 
       nydavarat och hemil. 
      Dist kyning. Kroska 
      bröllopskoordinator. Teletotal. 
      Mor tin. 
    </p>
    <p>
      Spejörar befaladat. Lavis 
      kvasideledes. 
      Dande dak. Anteck ur dick. 
      Skurkstat larad henifiera. Belogi 
      koliga selig. 
    </p>
    </div>
    <div className='service-list'>
      <ul id='top-list'>
        <li onClick={Changer}>
          <img src={oby} />
          {/* <div></div> */}
          <p>ob/gyn</p>
        </li>
        <li  onClick={Changer}>
          <img src={neuro} />
          {/* <div></div> */}
          <p>neurology</p>
        </li>
        <li  onClick={Changer}>
          <img src={peds}  />
          {/* <div></div> */}
          <p>pediatrics</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul id='bottom-list'>
        <li  onClick={Changer}>
          <img src={dental}/>
          {/* <div></div> */}
          <p>dental care</p>
        </li>
        <li  onClick={Changer}>
          <img src={cardio} />
          {/* <div></div> */}
          <p>cardiology</p>
        </li>
        <li  onClick={Changer}>
          <img src={ent} alt='E.N.T' />
          {/* <div></div> */}
          <p>ent</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

)
};

The `h2` tag is meant to take on the value of the `p` tags under the `li` element when clicked, I've figured out how to make the content in the service text shown when the li element is clicked.

what's troubling is how to change the value of the `h2` tag to whatever value the `p` tag of which `li` element is clicked.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the section titled "Write a title that summarizes the problem". The current title could "summarize" half of the React questions this site receives every day.

Answer (score 0):

[CodeSandBox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-morning-8jfi9h?file=/src/App.js)

Instead of using `useEffect`, `useRef`, you could simply use your `useState` to do all that.

I created a constant to make my/your life easier and just map though the elements (you don't need this, but I would recommend it)

```
const IMAGES = [
  { src: "oby", name: "ob/gyn" },
  { src: "neuro", name: "neurology" },
  { src: "peds", name: "pediatrics" },
  { src: "dental", name: "dental care" },
  { src: "cardio", name: "cardiology" },
  { src: "ent", name: "ent" }
];
```

```
<section className={title ? "serviceClicked" : "services"}>
      <h2>{title}</h2>
      ...
      <ul id="top-list">
            {IMAGES.map(({ src, name }) => {
              return (
                <li
                  key={name}
                  onClick={() => {
                    setTitle(name);
                  }}
                >
                  <img src={src} />
                  <h3>{name}</h3>
                </li>
              );
            })}
       </ul>
       ...
</section>
```

You would really want to use `useRef` if there's need to interact directly with the element, otherwise when dealing with only data `useState/useEffect` is more than enough.